# How to load image from url which I got via API calling

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, ios9

I want to use `UICollectionView` for displaying the images and I am getting that images by api calling.

Question: so I am getting images path via api calling so how can I display it to `UICollectionView`??

here is my code ::

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let dic = imagearray .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    let cell :imagecell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imagecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imagecell

    cell.imagev.image = dic["image"] as? UIImage
    return cell
}
```

and here is my api response

```
(
    {
    image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/esquire.jpg";
    slug = esquire;
},
    {
    image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/forbes.jpg";
    slug = forbes;
},
    {
    image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tapas.jpg";
    slug = tapas;
}
)
```

so how can I display this images in my `UICollectionView`

UPDATE:: While using commented code getting strange issue i am calling my webservice in viewdidload

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webimages()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

and its started to call webservice

```
func webimages()
{

let url = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/podcasts/"

    request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (response:Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in


           print(response.result.value)

            self.imagearray = (response.result.value) as! NSMutableArray
            print(self.imagearray)


    }

}
```

but after requesting its suddenly go to cellForItemAtIndexPath so my "imagearray" found nil there. and then its comeback to webimages() and giving me api response.

So how can I solve this?

[we have array of string we are passing single string here so can you please tell me that what is the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR3nK.png)

We have array of string we are passing single string here so can you please tell me that what is the solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfyPu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a URL string as UIImage. You first have to retrieve image from that URL first. Use the following method for quick remedy:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell :imagecell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imagecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imagecell
    if imagearray.count > 0 
    {
       let dic = imagearray .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

       let imgURL: NSString = dic!["image"] as! NSString //Get URL string
       let url = NSURL.URLWithString(imgURL); //Create URL
       var err: NSError?
       var imageData :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)! //Fetch Image Data
       var cellImage = UIImage(data:imageData) //Create UIImage from Image data
       cell.imagev.image = cellImage //Set image
    }

    return cell
}
```

Notice that this is fetching content of image URL in a synchronous call so that would freeze your UI until download completes. Also this is not caching the Image so images will be downloaded over and over again when you scroll and cells are recreated. To avoid that I'd suggest caching .

For better results, This is how you load image asynchronously, without freezing the UI and cache the images to avoid network load.

You first have to create a class first like this:

```
class ImageLoader {

var cache = NSCache() //Create cache

class var sharedLoader : ImageLoader {
    struct Static {
        static let instance : ImageLoader = ImageLoader()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

func imageForUrl(urlString: String , indexPathArg:NSIndexPath!, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String,indexPathResponse:NSIndexPath?) -> ()) {

    let currentIndexPath: NSIndexPath! = indexPathArg.mutableCopy() as! NSIndexPath

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {()in

        let data: NSData? = self.cache.objectForKey(urlString) as? NSData
        //Check if image data for this URL already exists in Cache
        if let goodData = data {
            //data exists, no need to download it again. Just send it
            let image = UIImage(data: goodData)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString,indexPathResponse: currentIndexPath)
            })
            return
        }
        //Data does not exist, We have to download it
        let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!,completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                //Download failed
                completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString, indexPathResponse: currentIndexPath)
                return
            }

            if data != nil {
                //Download successful,Lets save this downloaded data to our Cache and send it forward as UIImage
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.cache.setObject(data!, forKey: urlString)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                    completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString, indexPathResponse: currentIndexPath)
                })
                return
            }

        })
        downloadTask.resume()
    })

}
}
```

Then you have to modify your collectionview delegate like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell :imagecell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imagecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imagecell
    if imagearray.count > 0 
    {
       let dic = imagearray .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

       let imgURL: NSString = dic!["image"] as! NSString//Get URL string
       ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(imgURL as String,indexPathArg: indexPath, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String, indexPathResponse: NSIndexPath?) in


        let indexArr:NSArray = collectionView!.indexPathsForVisibleItems()

        if indexArr.containsObject(indexPathResponse!)
        {
            cell.imagev.image = image //Set image
        }

    })
    }


    return cell
}
```

Now it will load your image asynchronously and will download it only if necessary. Great Success! (To quote Borat). I have added comments so that you can understand What's going on in my code and Daniel's code :)

To Fix your crash issue which is not a part of your original question and instead a  different problem you created, Return count of items in section to be count of your image array and reload collectionview once you have retrieved your data:

```
func webimages()
{

let url = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/podcasts/"

    request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (response:Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in


           print(response.result.value)

            self.imagearray = (response.result.value) as! NSMutableArray
            print(self.imagearray)
            //Reload Collection view
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }

}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imagearray.count
}
```

Credits for Imageloader class: [Daniel Sattler](https://teamtreehouse.com/danielsattler)

Special Thanks to: [CouchDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465677/couchdeveloper)

Comment: The guy who downvoted, Why did you downvote? :D Care to explain?

Comment: even i dont know why people are downvoting without any reason.?

Comment: Ikr. xD Suppose I should add the Asynchronous method as well.

Comment: There's one issue with your approach: since cells are reused and you are loading asynchronously, you cannot use the _cell_ in the completion handler: in the meantime the cell might now displaying _another_ row. Fix: use the index path. Then in the completion handler, check if there's a cell for the index path, if yes update the cell - otherwise ignore. Another issue, is that you need to limit the number of network requests and prioritise or cancel them. But this goes far beyond what can be explained in a comment ;)

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'  getting this error after using this @NSNoob how can i solve it?

Comment: @Govind The error is on `let dic = imagearray .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary` Your imagearray is empty. this imagearray should be the response array you get from web service. (The one which you shared)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I don't know how to prioritize requests, So if you have time could you please add it? It could help many!

Comment: @NSNoob Instead doing something complicated, simple cancel the request for a cell that's being reused (although, when caching images we might consider to choose a more complicated solution). We can accomplish this by either subclassing the image cell: start the network request, handle the completion, and cancel the request. For example, in `prepareForReuse` cancel a pending request. Or, alternatively, subclass `UIImageView`. There are already solutions posted on SO for doing this.

Comment: @Govind Great then mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy you got to downlaod the image from that url and set it as the image for the image view,

Try this, https://github.com/natelyman/SwiftImageLoader

Add the ImageLoader class to your project and modify the collectionview data source as below,

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let dic = imagearray .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
let cell :imagecell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imagecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imagecell

//cell.imagev.image = dic["image"] as? UIImage

ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(dic["image"], completionHandler:    {(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
     cell.imagev.image = image
})

return cell
}
```

This is an asynchronous image loading class so UI would not freeze or give you any other problems if you are against using any third party libs or classes please do it manually as @NSNoob 's answer.

Other good image loading libraries are,

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/blob/master/Spring/AsyncImageView.swift

https://github.com/anas10/AsyncImageView-Swift

Comment: What the hell?? Who is down voting this answer?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but actually it's justified: cells are reused, that is they can "point" to different rows. When your completion handler tries to set the image for a certain row, it's corresponding cell might already render another row. So, in order to fix it, you need to import the _index path_ into the completion handler, then obtain the cell from the index path, and if it still exists (that is, the row is still visible) set the image. Otherwise, ignore. There's another issue with your approach (see other comment regarding @NSNoob solution).

Comment: its give me this error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'  @satheeshwaran

Comment: @Govind Problem is with your data array. Not with Satesshwaran's solution

Comment: (
    {
    image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/esquire.jpg";
    slug = esquire;
},
    {
    image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/forbes.jpg";
    slug = forbes;
},
    {
    image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tapas.jpg";
    slug = tapas;
}
)
 this is my response array what is problem with this can you please help me to find out sollution @NSNoob

Comment: This response array is not being used to populate the collection view Govind. the array which you are using to populate your cells is empty. I have already told you the solution

Comment: thanks @NSNoob finally got my problem.. problem: my webservice start calling in viewdidload() but its give response after calling "cellForItemAtIndexPath" so  my array is nil while setting value in cellForItemAtIndexPath. so how can i solve it

Comment: Show a spinner while your web service is busy fetching response, when response is received, then reload the collectionView. Also always check your arrays for their count before getting their objects from index. @Govind

Answer (score 0):

You can extend UIImageView as following -

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromU(urlString: String) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let imageData = data as NSData? {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in any UIImageView you will have a very simple helper method as follows -

```
yourImageView.imageFromURL("https://yoururl.com/image.png")
```

And in your case

```
cell.imagev.image.imageFromURL(dic["image"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
            imageURL!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            imageURL!.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
```